# How to record my calls on Nexus 4 with Android 4.4.2?

Tags: nexus-4, voice-recording

I've got a Nexus 4 with Android 4.4.2 and want to record my voice calls.

My first idea was to simply use a recording app, so I've tried a whole bunch of call recording apps, but none of them work. They only record my voice, not the other side. Or they require the speaker / handsfree mode in order to record the other person (and then still sounds like crap).

After some reading it seems not all phones/models support full 2-way voice recording. However I did read some claims about people pulling ot off on Nexus 4 (although it's not clear to me if this necessarily involves rooting and/or custom roms, which I'd rather avoid).

Is there ANY way (preferably without rooting) to do proper 2-way phone call recording on a Nexus 4 running Android 4.4.2?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Easy Voice Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coffeebeanventures.easyvoicerecorder). It works for me (Nexus 4, Android 4.4.2 without root).

When you have root privileged, it is much easier. But without root, I don't know any apps that can record the other side in a way that you can hear him "clean". But as I said, Easy Voice Recorder did a very good job for me. Not perfect (crystal clear), but good (I can here the other side in the record without any issues).

Comment: Yes, actually I always use Easy Voice Recorder for normal audio recording. Great app. But it doesn't really work with phone calls for me. I tried it, and although it does record something when the other person talks, but it's extremely low volume and very noisy/compressed/disturbed. I've even tried recording at highest quality (PCM or highest AAC)  and post-processing the resulting audio file, boosting the volume 100x (by 10,000%), and then I hear *something*, but it's still mostly unrecognizable.

Comment: The best advice i can give you is to root your phone, i don't know of any app that equals the quality from a an record app with root privilege.

Comment: Rooting the phone will make no difference to voice recording incoming/outgoing calls as that is walled off from the proprietary telephony chipset used and hence no one has actually done that for that very simple reason. And to record the other end is totally grey area, the person would have to give you consent to do so, IANAL but broach this carefully.

Answer (score 1):

2-way call recording on Nexus 4 is disabled by the manufacturer.
If you have root, try [Jit Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.UIApps.JitCallRecorder.App), it records both sides of the call very well

Answer (score 0):

Call recording for non-rooted phones seem to only work with the Mic mode, when your speaker is on. This makes your volume not so clear. I tested this with [Automatic Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorder).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need hardware support in your kernel and root access for line recording. Otherwise you're stuck with mic recording, which only picks up your voice (at least on my Nexus 4)

The only one that worked for me was [this "Call Recorder"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skvalex.callrecorder) app. It costs $10 and requires root access, but it does a pretty good job. There's a trial version link on the Play page, you might want to try that and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

CallRecorder [from XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1441643) this is the only APP that allowed me to record my conversations properly, I own a Samsung SGH-i537 (S4 Active) and Samsung decided not to allow native recording for it, so you HAVE to root your phone before installing this APP (in the link there's a trial version so you can see if it works on your phone).

Answer (score 0):

I tested Boldbeast Recorder (the special version provided by the developer). This is a free app, and it works very well for my LGE Nexus 4. It records calls perfectly in two directions.

Have a look at what settings you should use in the app suggested by the developer.

[Link to the XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=56507567&postcount=98)

Answer (score 0):

I updated my Nexus 4 from Android 4.4.2 to 4.4.4, 5.0, 5.0.1 and 5.0.2. From my experience only Boldbeast Call Recorder ([Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boldbeast.recorder)) works well for all these Android versions.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the [Total Recall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.killermobile.totalrecall) call recorder application on your Nexus 4 smartphone.

Answer (score -1):

Try this android call recorder, Which i had found in
 [XDA Forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/general/android-call-recorder-smartphone-app-t3073998)